# How to show child radwindow on its parent radwindow manually?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dialog, resize, radwindow

I am creating two radwindow dialogs: a parent and its child. 
Parent radwindow has size 1082x630

Child radwindow has size 1500x900

On parent radwindow dialog, when I click on button "Show Child Dialog", its child radwindow will be shown.

The problem here is the size of child dialog larger than its parent. So, I want to resize the size of child dialog and show it in the center of its parent dialog.

And here is my code in Javascript that I use for resizing child dialog manually. To center child dialog, I also use childRadWindow.left and childRadWindow.top . **BUT, it does not work as my expected. The child dialog does not place in the center of its parent**.

Please reference my expected, actual images and my code to get the problem.

My expected result:
[image]

Actual result: 
[image]

Here is my code to resize child dialog manually. I put it on child dialog *.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         resizeRWndDialog();
     });       
</script>
function resizeRWndDialog() {
    var radWindows = [];
    var radWindow = GetRadWindow();
    while (true) {
        if (radWindow != undefined && radWindow != null) {
            radWindows.push(radWindow._popupElement);
            radWindow = radWindow.BrowserWindow.GetRadWindow();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    var numsOfRadWindow = radWindows.length - 1;
    if (numsOfRadWindow > 0) {
        for (var i = numsOfRadWindow; i > 0; i--) {
            var parentWindow = radWindows[i];
            var parentWidth = parentWindow.clientWidth;   //parentWidth =1082
            var parentHeight = parentWindow.clientHeight; //parentHeight = 630

            var chidWindow = radWindows[i - 1];
            var childWidth = chidWindow.clientWidth;    //childWidth = 1500
            var childHeight = chidWindow.clientHeight;  //childHeight = 900

            var rateMinWidth = 0,
                rateMinHeight = 0,
                rateMaxWidth = 0,
                rateMaxHeight = 0;

            if (chidWindow.style.minWidth != "") {
                rateMinWidth = parseInt(chidWindow.style.minWidth) / childWidth;
            }

            if (chidWindow.style.minHeight != "") {
                rateMinHeight = parseInt(chidWindow.style.minHeight) / childHeight;
            }

            if (chidWindow.style.maxWidth != "") {
                rateMaxWidth = parseInt(chidWindow.style.maxWidth) / childWidth;
            }

            if (chidWindow.style.maxHeight != "") {
                rateMaxHeight = parseInt(chidWindow.style.maxHeight) / childHeight;
            }

            if ((parentWidth - 40) > 0 && childWidth >= parentWidth - 40) {
                childWidth = parentWidth - 40;    //parentWidth = 1082, childWidth = 1042
            }

            if ((parentHeight - 80) > 0 && childHeight >= parentHeight - 80) {
                childHeight = parentHeight - 80;    //parentHeight = 630, childHeight = 550
            }

            setSizeRWndDialog(chidWindow.getElementsByClassName("rwTable")[0], rateMinWidth * childWidth, rateMinHeight * childHeight, rateMaxWidth * childWidth, rateMaxHeight * childHeight, childWidth, childHeight);
            setSizeRWndDialog(chidWindow, rateMinWidth * childWidth, rateMinHeight * childHeight, rateMaxWidth * childWidth, rateMaxHeight * childHeight, childWidth, childHeight);

            chidWindow.left = Math.round((parentWidth - childWidth) / 2, 0) + "px";
            chidWindow.top = Math.round((parentHeight - childHeight) / 2, 0) + "px";
            chidWindow.focus();
            radWindows[i - 1] = chidWindow;
        }
    }
}

function setSizeRWndDialog(element, minWidth, minHeight, maxWidth, maxHeight, width, height) {
    if (minWidth != 0 && minHeight != 0) {
        element.style.minWidth = minWidth + "px";
        element.style.minHeight = minHeight + "px";
    }

    if (maxWidth != 0 && maxHeight != 0) {
        element.style.maxWidth = maxWidth + "px";
        element.style.maxHeight = maxHeight + "px";
    } else {
        element.style.maxWidth = width + "px";
        element.style.maxHeight = height + "px";
    }

    element.style.width = width + "px";
    element.style.height = height + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself, guys. 
I just added one more line at the end of the resizeRWndDialog() as the snippet code below:

```
function resizeRWndDialog() {
    //.........
    if (numsOfRadWindow > 0) {
        //...........
    }
    GetRadWindow().center(); // >> Just use this line
}
```